# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am currently trying to implement caching for my application and I am facing an error of "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:annotation-driven'." in my pom.xml. Am I missing anything here?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="packages path" />

<!-- Enables the caching through annotations -->
<cache:annotation-driven />

<!-- Generic cache manager based on the JDK ConcurrentMap -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                p:name="task" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order in the attribute schemaLocation is wrong. Instead of

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
```

it should be

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
```

The values in schemaLocation consists always of pairs of elements. The first element denotes the identifier of the schema, which is used in the xmlns attributes, the second element of each pair denotes then the location of the xsd file. In your code you basically tell the parser, that the xsd file for the identifier `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` is located at `http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache` and the xsd file for the identifier `http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd` is located at `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd`.